# What mitzvos are under the umbrella term מתן שכרה בצידה referenced in the Jerusalem Talmud Bava Basra

Tags: reward-punishment, talmud-yerushalmi

The gemara in the Jerusalem Talmud Bava Batra (cited [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bava_Batra.18a.2?lang=bi)) refers to a collective set of commandments called "מתן שכרה בצידה", which I believe can be loosely translated as "reward given on the side" and I parenthetically add, (in this world). It is my understanding that there are 2 mitzvot referenced in the Torah that can be categorized as such, namely שילוח הקו (sending away the mother bird) and כיבוד אב ואם,(honoring one's father and mother) which both come with a reward of אריכת ימים, which is simply translated as, "length of days". Can someone inform me if there are other mitzvot that are considered to fall under the category of "מתן שכרה בצידה" besides the 2 mitzvot referenced above and what they are along with their respective rewards?

Comment: There are more than two mitzvot that come with "length of days" reward in the verses. You've probably just heard of those two since there's a famous midrash about them

Comment: For a start, there’s the mitzvah that the Yerushalmi is referring to there: not having incorrect weights and measures

Comment: The flip side of all of this is the Sifri Bamidbar 115:2 which says rather definitively - "רבי נתן אומר אין כל מצוה ומצוה שאין מתן שכרה בצדה" - "Rabbi Noson said: There is no mitzvah in the Torah whose reward is not "at its side." He goes on to bring the case of Tzitzis to prove this.